# Loop-invariant, Hoare logic

Tags: logic

What is the loop-invariant for this problem? The only invariant I can think of is x=(x-y)+y but it feels wrong since it doesn't say much more than x=x.

EDIT: Is the invariant just ⊤?
[image]

Comment: Please use mathjax to write your question.  This is short; no need to say more in an image, than you did through typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\geq y$ looks like a good invariant to me.